# NSDictionary App Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, nsdictionary

Trying to read a plist and change my font color depending on the option that was selected in the following settings bundle.
[image]

The following is how I am trying to accomplish it:

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/NCNotes.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
fontSize = [[dict objectForKey:@"slideSwitched"] floatValue];

if ([[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"] valueForKey:@"Purple"]) {
   noteView.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
} else {
    noteView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Any ideas why this is why my app is crashing? How do I read the values and change the color depending on what was selected?

Comment: try something like

if ([[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"] isEqualTo:@"Purple"])

Comment: You've asked this before.  the answer then was "There is no `key` named "noteColor".  There is a `key` named "key" with a value of "noteColor"..."

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the top level of your plist is an array, not a dictionary, because at the top it says "Item 1" where all of your content is within that. So you have a dictionary within an array. So you can change your code like this:

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/NCNotes.plist";
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dict = array[0];
```

You could also change the structure of your plist so that you have a dictionary as the root instead of an array.

Also, keys are supposed to be on the left-hand side and their values on the right-hand side, so I don't see a key "noteColor". You have a key "key" with a value "noteColor", so you'll need to make that correction. I'm also not seeing a "slideSwitched" key, though it might just be outside the bounds of your screenshot.

Also the following won't work:

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"] valueForKey:@"Purple"]
```

Whatever you get from `[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"]` isn't going to be a dictionary, so calling `valueForKey:` on that isn't going to give you what you want.

Comment: How do you know I have a key "key" with a value "noteColor". I thought it would be a key with object "noteColor"

Comment: How should I go about determining which value was selected?

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows an entry in your plist file where the key is "key" and the value is "noteColor". That's how I know.

Comment: So it should be objectForKey: key valueForKey:noteColor?

Comment: What am I missing here? Still not understanding fully.

Comment: If you do `[dict objectForKey:@"noteColor"]`, you'll get nothing because you have nothing in your dictionary under the key "noteColor". And if you did `[dict objectForKey:@"key"]`, you would get the string "noteColor", because that's what you have stored under that key.

Comment: So whats the proper way of determining what color was selected using the key as the identifier for that dictionary?

Comment: @AnthonyGeranio Perhaps you need to study a tutorial on how plists and `NSDictionary`s work. You can also experiment with working with your particular dictionary using the debugger.

Comment: Also, don't mix `objectForKey:` and `valueForKey:` either.  Use the former when hitting dictionaries and the latter when hitting objects for properties along key paths (read more about KVO, if you're interested in that).

Answer (score 0):

simply you should do this with document directory

```
 NSString *contentPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PLIST_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:contentPath];
```

write your logic after this, wait a minute , its seems like you dont have a key "noteColor" also. check your plist

Comment: I thought I would have a key called "noteColor" with my plist. Am I doing something wrong identifying the key?

Comment: yes, i found whats the problem. you should choose the root of plist as array, not dictionary. that array will have 9 dictionary. check it

Comment: one more thing , noteColor is not key . its value for your key "key". check in your plist. left is key, right is value

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code documented up the wazoo.  Hopefully it will help you understand how these plists and dictionaries work.  Everything will be based on your plist file (which could definitely be improved upon, but that's up to you as I don't know your specific situation).

Your question is "How do I find color based on user selection?"  I will assume you get the user selection as an int.  Something like "User selected 7".

```
//Load your plist dictionary
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/NCNotes.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

//Get the array of validValues and the array of validTitles
NSArray *valuesArray = [dict objectForKey:@"validValues"];
NSArray *titlesArray = [dict objectForKey:@"validTitles"];

//Now get the user selected index from the validValues array
int arraySelection = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < [valuesArray count]; i++)
{
    NSNumber *number = [valuesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if([number intValue] == userSelectedInput)
    {
        arraySelection = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(arraySelection == -1)
{
    //Not found in array
    return;
}

//Now with that index get the title of the object that the user selected
NSString *userSelectedTitle = [titlesArray objectAtIndex:arraySelection];

//Now do your checking on what the user selected based on that:
if([userSelectedTitle isEqualToString:@"Purple"])

...
```

You could boil this down quite a bit.  Currently your `validValues` array is completely useless.  If it were out of order or missing numbers then it would be needed, but straight counting can be achieved by the validTitles array.

Comment: It says that if userSelectedInput is an int I cannot convert that value

Comment: @AnthonyGeranio I updated my answer.  I noticed that your valuesArray is numbers instead of strings.  but I still say you can get rid of the values array if they are monotonic.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm missing something but it seems that my view wont load entirely when nothing is found in the array.